# Apache NiFi: MergeContent do not merges files properly

Tags: merge, salesforce, apache-nifi

I have the following flow:

1. I get data from Salesforce but there is a lot of data (10000 records), so I have to use *nextUrl* attribute to get next batches with 1000 records. That is why the first file comes from one flow and all others are coming from another flow (using nextUrl attribute).
2. In general 1 file comes from the 1st flow and 8 files come from the 2nd flow, and then I split JSON, so there are 1000 records in the first flow and 8000 records in the second flow.
3. Then I have to merge 1000 + 8000 records into 1 file. But in result there is not 1 file but 9 files (as it was in the beginning when JSON was not split yet). And only when I use one more MergeContent processor, finally I have 1 file instead of 9 files.

I have the following configuration for MergeContent:

- Merge Strategy: Bin-Packing Algorithm;
- Merge Format: Binary Concatenation;
- Attribute Strategy: Keep Only Common Attributes.

Actually I tried other parameters as well but all data is combined into 1 file only using the second MergeContent.

Please help me to figure out why it happens and if there is a way to use only one MergeContent processor?
If you need any additional information, just let me know.

Comment: have you tried MergeRecord?

Comment: Have you configured the rest of properties for `MergeContent` or just left as default?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde no, all other properties are left as default. And actually it works fine for other flows but not for this one.

Comment: @Sdairs thanks, I didn't try it, will try this component as well.